# Can't set the .innerHTML of an <span> created dynamically (Angular)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dynamic, getelementbyid

I'm trying to change the text inside a <'span> generated dynamically.
The <'span> is generated inside a list (<'ul><'li>) that change its number of item (li) if a selection was changed.

this is the dynamic list (it works)

```
<ul *ngIf="placeholder[0]">
  <li *ngFor="let time of placeholder[0], let i = index" >
    <div><span id="timer0{{i}}"> lol </span><span *ngIf="timer[0].timeLeft[i] > 0"> : {{timer[0].timeLeft[i]}} secondi <button (click)="restart(0, i)"> reset qua</button><button (click)="check()"> check div</button></span></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is the Typescript code in which i'm trying to change the text inside the `<span id = "timer0{{i}}">`

```
setTime(i: number){
    //setting del timer (azzero tutti i campi)
    this.placeholder[i]=[]

    this.timer[i].lunghezza = Object.keys(this.datiX.fileJson.ricette[this.datiX.postazioniNome[this.datiX.defPostazione]][this.datiX.ricetta[i]]).length;

    for (let j = 0; j < this.timer[i].lunghezza; j++) {    
      this.placeholder[i][j] = [""]
    }

    for (let j = 0; j < this.timer[i].lunghezza; j++) {    
      this.pauseTimer(i, j);

      this.timer[i].inizio[j] = 0;
      this.timer[i].fine[j] = Object.keys(this.datiX.fileJson.ricette[this.datiX.postazioniNome[this.datiX.defPostazione]][this.datiX.ricetta[i]][j]).length;
      this.timer[i].timeLeft[j] = <number> <unknown>Object.keys(this.datiX.fileJson.ricette[this.datiX.postazioniNome[this.datiX.defPostazione]][this.datiX.ricetta[i]][j][0])[this.timer[i].inizio[j]];
    }

    console.log("check: ",document.getElementById('timer01'))

  }
```

**console.log("check: ",document.getElementById('timer01'))** gives me = `null` inside the function, but if i call a function (after pressing the check button) that print it, it gives me the correct value ("lol")...

what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I guess it's a timing issue - the element has probably not been created yet when setTime() runs.

Comment: the element is created inside the setTime() function.. there's a way to wait until it's fully created?

Comment: id="" expect a string value. Check your devtools, you should see id="timer0{{i}}" for each item rather than id="timer01". Try with [id]="timer0{{i}}"

Comment: nope, the span id are created dynamically and the {{i}} value is taken from "let i = index" inside the <'li> tag. i've checked and they works fine (their id are "timer00", "timer01"...)

Comment: Is the element inserted in the DOM after its creation? because for the `document.getElementById` to work you need that the element is in the DOM, not just in a variable

Comment: ciao Andrea, credo tu sia italiano ':D
il DOM? scusa son un novizio di angular...
comunque credo sia apposto perché se premo il pulsante di "check" (e testo con un id statico, tipo "timer 01") mi viene restituito il tag completo... quindi credo sia un problema di timing